# Nesting django Q objects to filter relations

Tags: python, django

I am using `Django 2.0` and am generating a rather complex filter from user input that I want to store in the database.

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(...)
    doors = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)

class Tire(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name="tires")
    radius = models.FloatField(...)
    color = models.CharField(...)
```

I now would like to create filters both for `Car` and for `Tire` *before* evaluating or setting up any querysets, i.e., I only want the complete `Q()` object:

```
my_filter = Q(brand__startswith='Volks') & Q(doors=4)
my_tire_filter = Q(radius__range=(1.0, 2.0) & Q(color=black))
```

How can I now *create another `Q` object* for the `Car` model, giving me cars that fulfill `my_filter` and have tires fulfilling `my_tire_filter`? Something like

```
my_car_filter = my_filter & Q(tires=my_tire_filter)
the_cars = Car.objects.get(my_car_filter)
```

I want to store these `Q()` objects serialized in the database, that's why I need the pure `Q` filter without any datasets. Is that possible?